# Does Insert require a commit statement

Tags: oracle

I am inserting few records into an oracle table. Does it require "COMMIT" statement.
if Yes, in that case, If I am inserting 10 different rows, do I need to give commit after every insert statement.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Yes. You need to commit after insert in Oracle. For multiple statements, one commit is enough at the end of all inserts

Example:

```
--Example 1

Insert into table(col1) values(val1);
commit;

--Example 2
Insert into table(col1) values(val1);
Insert into table(col2) values(val2);
Insert into table(col3) values(val3);
Insert into table(col4) values(val4);
commit;
```

Both are legal. Example 1 will insert 1 row and Example 2 will insert 4 rows.

Answer (score 0):

It has some different from the way to using 'commit' keyword.
Here is some example cases:
exp 1:

```
insert into tableA(colA) values(valA);
commit;
insert into tableA(colA) values(valB);
commit;
```

=> If 2nd of insert statement got any error but 1st of insert statement still be inserted successfully into DB.

exp 2:

```
insert into tableA(colA) values(valA);
insert into tableA(colA) values(valB);
commit;
```

=> If 2nd of insert statement got any error then 1st of insert statement could not be inserted successfully into DB.

So, it's depended on your purposed to do with its.